# How to stop Windows from loading the default account at startup

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, user-profiles

Is there a way to prevent Windows from loading the default account at startup?

One can press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to stop the loading but by then the default account is already loading.

**Is there some keyboard combination to get Windows to *NOT* load any profile at all and just present the account selection/login page?**

Comment: Default user contains lot of required data, for ex. start user selection page. What is the problem with default user?

Comment: It doesn't load any account if password id required.

Comment: I have 3 local Windows user accounts on my machine. One has full admin rights and is password protected. The other have NO admin rights and one of them is set to load by default.

Sometimes I may want to login with the admin account and don't to first the default user profile and then sign out or switch users.

**Is there a way to stop Windows from loading the default user profile?**

Comment: So, to put it succinctly, you wish to see the login page every time the computer powers on?

Comment: Does the "default" user account have a password?

Comment: No I only sporadically want to choose another user account. Say I want to upgrade a software for which I need a user with Windows admin rights.Then it rather tedious having to first load the default account only to sign out afterwards and sign in with the admin user.  A waste of time don't you think?  
No the default user account does not have a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys to open the Run dialog box, type **netplwiz** or **control userpasswords2**
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on OK to open advanced User Accounts
3. Check the **Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer** box, and click on OK

[Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html#option1)

Comment: Brilliant, This is exactly what I wanted